# Insert Multiple record in database laravel 8

Tags: laravel, foreach

I need to insert all the number in my database. I used foreach loop to view students and marks to insert.

When click save all data of class test partA partB will store in database.
I am facing difficulties in controller

[image]

```
`<form action="{{ route('teacher.add_all_student_results',[$session_id,$semester_id,$course_id,$course_credit]) }}" method="POST">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>IMG</th>
                        {{-- <th>Department Name</th> --}}
                        <th>Reg.No</th>
                        <th>ID.No</th>
                        <th>Student Name</th>
                        <th>Attendance</th>
                        <th>Class Test</th>
                        <th>PartA</th>
                        <th>PartB</th>
                        {{--  --}}
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        @csrf
                        @php $i=1;
                        @endphp
                        @foreach($semester_students as $semester_student)
                        <tr data-widget="expandable-table" aria-expanded="false">
                            <td>
                                <input type="hidden" name="student_id" value={{ $semester_student->id }} placeholder="add marks" class="form-control">
                            </td>
                            <td><img class="img-circle img-bordered-sm" src="" alt="U" width="50"></td>
                            <td>{{$semester_student->registration_number}}</td>
                            <td>{{$semester_student->roll_number}}</td>
                            <td>{{$semester_student->firstname}} {{$semester_student->lastname}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="attendance" placeholder="add marks" class="form-control">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="class_test" placeholder="add marks" class="form-control">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="parta" placeholder="add marks" class="form-control">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="partb" placeholder="add marks" class="form-control">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-1"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"
                aria-hidden="true"></i>
            Save</button>
        </form>`
```

Comment: Please format your question so it is readable.

Comment: I did please check it just insert the foreach value in database

Answer (score -1):

To use multiple inputs by looping them you need to define input names as arrays.

For example;

```
<input name="student_id[]">
<input name="student_id[]">
<input name="student_id[]">
<input name="student_id[]">
<input name="student_id[]">
```

If I place this inputs in a form and submit it, I can receive `request()->input('student_id')` as an array which contains all 5 values in it.

So, in your foreach loop you need to define every multiple input as an array.

Also you can give custom indexes to them to fetch them easily. For example;

```
<input name="student_data[][student_id]">
<input name="student_data[][student_id]">
<input name="student_data[][student_id]">
<input name="student_data[][student_id]">
<input name="student_data[][student_id]">
```

Now you can access all looped rows with `request()->input('student_data')` or directly `request()->student_data`

It will be an array and you can use it in a foreach. `dd(request()->student_data)` for example;

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "student_id" => "123"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "student_id" => "234"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "student_id" => "345"
  ]
  3 => array:1 [▼
    "student_id" => "456"
  ]
  4 => array:1 [▼
    "student_id" => "567"
  ]
]
```

Now if you give them manual indexes for each row, yo can group everything together;

```
<input name="student_data[0][student_id]">
<input name="student_data[0][student_name]">
<input name="student_data[1][student_id]">
<input name="student_data[1][student_name]">
<input name="student_data[2][student_id]">
<input name="student_data[2][student_name]">
<input name="student_data[3][student_id]">
<input name="student_data[3][student_name]">
<input name="student_data[4][student_id]">
<input name="student_data[4][student_name]">
```

Now `request()->student_data` will be like this;

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "student_id" => "1"
    "student_name" => "1st name"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "student_id" => "2"
    "student_name" => "2nd name"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "student_id" => "3"
    "student_name" => "3rd name"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "student_id" => "4"
    "student_name" => "4th name"
  ]
  4 => array:2 [▼
    "student_id" => "5"
    "student_name" => "5th name"
  ]
]
```

So; you need to update your inputs' names.

```
<form action="{{ route('teacher.add_all_student_results',[$session_id,$semester_id,$course_id,$course_credit]) }}"
    method="POST">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>IMG</th>
                {{-- <th>Department Name</th> --}}
                <th>Reg.No</th>
                <th>ID.No</th>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Attendance</th>
                <th>Class Test</th>
                <th>PartA</th>
                <th>PartB</th>
                {{--  --}}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @csrf
            @php $i=1;
            @endphp
            @foreach($semester_students as $semester_student)
            <tr data-widget="expandable-table" aria-expanded="false">
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="student_data[{{ $semester_student->id }}][student_id]" value={{ $semester_student->id }} placeholder="add marks"
                        class="form-control">
                </td>
                <td><img class="img-circle img-bordered-sm" src="" alt="U" width="50"></td>
                <td>{{$semester_student->registration_number}}</td>
                <td>{{$semester_student->roll_number}}</td>
                <td>{{$semester_student->firstname}} {{$semester_student->lastname}}</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="student_data[{{ $semester_student->id }}][attendance]" placeholder="add marks" class="form-control">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="student_data[{{ $semester_student->id }}][class_test]" placeholder="add marks" class="form-control">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="student_data[{{ $semester_student->id }}][parta]" placeholder="add marks" class="form-control">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="student_data[{{ $semester_student->id }}][partb]" placeholder="add marks" class="form-control">
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-1"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        Save</button>
</form>
```

Now use it in your controller as `request()->student_data`

Let's loop it;

```
foreach(request()->student_data as $student_id => $student_row) {
    // you can do whatever you want with each row
    $student_row['attendance']; // you can access all inputs in this way and run your insert queries for each of rows
}
```

If you want to use validation on array inputs you can still achieve it;

```
$request->validate([
    'student_data.*.student_id' => 'required|numeric',
    'student_data.*.attendance' => 'required',
    // and others...
]);
```